# How to parsing google maps for H2/Title/NAP and send it to the Google Sheet?

Tags: google-business-profile

Need to get NAP and h2/title tags from google business profiles. And all these stuff send to google sheet. Maybe you can recommend me the way how can I do that? Maybe I should not do this manually, cause there is some tool for that?

I need to parse all SEO companies in Toronto, but it's possible only with my GMB profile, only with (https://seotwix.com/)
I could not use importXML formula, because of the google maps application is fully JS pulling.

Answer (score 0):

Try using proper tools (automation framework + scraping engine) and use Google Sheets just for basic storage purposes:
https://youtu.be/uBC752CWTew (Pipedream for automation + ScrapeNinja engine for scraping)